# Shift register does not output voltage

Tags: arduino, transistors, led, npn, shift-register

I am building a 8x8x8 LED cubic matrix based on an Arduino. My schematic and PCB design was based on the one posted by [Tapendra Mandal on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN5JWQUfrxY&list=PL5nfF_hVijdSOX4WSv3J2h_pm0C3huZQK&index=66&t=507s).

When I finally connected everything and try to write 1 to all registers, the cube isn't working as it should be (i.e. every LED lit.)

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Here is my schematic:

[image]

Please ask anything you want to know where I don't make it clear

Comment: Difficult to say what happens without a scope. The transistors need base resistors, and there aren't nearly enough decoupling capacitors.

Comment: what have you tested so far? There could be 100's of possibilities of a single error causing the failure, so you need to work logically to determine what is working and what isn't. For all we know, you leds could be wired backwards. The transistors might be backwards and so it goes. I would start with a multimeter and check to see you are getting 5V to where you expect.

Comment: Would you mind telling what parts you used? What shift register and transistors? All other parts have their values missing as well. What voltages are used to power different chips? And why are base resistors for the transistors missing?

Comment: I used 74hc595 shift register, SS8050SOT-23 transistor(NPN), the power supply is 5V 4A. This may sound silly but I had no previous experience in using transistors so I just copied the schematic of other people(link above). Thank you

Comment: 8 x 8 x 8 = 512 Leds ... So 8 * 64 outputs. Check first one at one time, 74hc595 registers ...

Comment: did you test the circuit with one shift register, one transistor and one LED?

Answer (score 1):

Do some methodical debugging. You'll need to figure out if it's a hardware problem or a software problem.

Hardware:

- Are the shift register outputs giving the expected high / low output signals.
- If so, are the transistors giving the expected output signals.
- If both of those are OK then you have an LED wiring problem.

Software:

- Can you modify the program to switch the outputs on and off at a rate that would be detectable using your multimeter (assuming you don't have an oscilloscope)?
- When you modify the software can you see any changes on the data lines?

Comment: I wrote the program to write 72 HIGHs to the 9 registers. Each ouput pin gives around 0.2V relative to GND, and there's no voltage between LEDs. LED wiring has been checked correct with correct polarity. Could it be problems with transistors? Thank you for your help and time!